# Nested For Each and If Then statements works but doesn't continue to Next sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Please excuse my novice, Frankenstein VBA coding. I've managed to get this code to work properly on the first qualifying sheet, but then it doesn't continue looping through the rest of the sheets. Here's what I need it to do:

I have a large number of sheets named with ID strings. For each sheet that isn't called "Raw Data" or "Pivot", I need it to:

- search column C on sheet("Raw Data") for values that match the name of the current sheet in the loop
- copy that row and transpose it to a column starting with B2 of the current sheet
- continue to the next matching value and transpose that row on the next column to the right
- when there are no more matching values, move to the next sheet and do it all again

Right now it works for the first sheet and then I get nothing. I don't know if it's because I've set up the nested loops incorrectly, or if it's not searching the values properly (like pasting down a vlookup without locking the references)

```vb
Sub copyrows2()
    Dim Scol As Range, Cell As Object, rawdata As Worksheet, WS As Worksheet, lc As Long, C As Integer

    Set rawdata = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")
    Set Scol = rawdata.Range("C2:C2000") 'Substitute with the range which includes your True/False values
    C = 2

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If WS.Name <> "Raw Data" And WS.Name <> "Pivot" Then
            With WS 'cycles through all of the sheets with Franchise ID's as the name
                For Each Cell In Scol 'should scan the C column on the Raw Data sheet'
                    If IsEmpty(Cell) Then
                        Exit Sub
                    End If

                    If Cell.Value = WS.Name Then 'checks for cells that contain the same Franchise ID as the current sheet in the cycle'
                        Cell.EntireRow.Copy
                        WS.Cells(2, C).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
                            xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
                        C = C + 1
                    End If
                Next Cell
            End With
        End If
    Next WS

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

I'm not getting any error messages, the loop just doesn't appear to continue like it's supposed to.

Update: I'm an idiot, @GSerg fixed the looping issue by pointing out that I had Exit Sub in the middle of the code.

Now, on each successive page it's picking up on the column where it left off (instead of starting back over at B2). Do I need to tell it to reset to C=2 after the End If? Like:

````vb
If Cell.Value = WS.Name Then 'checks for cells that contain the same Franchise ID as the current sheet in the cycle'
                        Cell.EntireRow.Copy
                        WS.Cells(2, C).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
                            xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
                        C = C + 1
                    End If
                    C = 2
                Next Cell

Update 2: I think I fixed it. Instead of setting C=2 at the beginning of the macro, or resetting it after that IF statement, I set C=2 at the beginning of the outer loop so that it would reset the value at each sheet:

```vb
Sub copyrows2()
    Dim Scol As Range, Cell As Object, rawdata As Worksheet, WS As Worksheet, lc As Long, C As Integer

    Set rawdata = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")
    Set Scol = rawdata.Range("C2:C2000") 'Substitute with the range which includes your True/False values

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If WS.Name <> "Raw Data" And WS.Name <> "Pivot" Then
            With WS 'cycles through all of the sheets with Franchise ID's as the name
            C=2 'This is the fix'
                For Each Cell In Scol 'should scan the C column on the Raw Data sheet'
                    If IsEmpty(Cell) Then
                        Exit Sub
                    End If

                    If Cell.Value = WS.Name Then 'checks for cells that contain the same Franchise ID as the current sheet in the cycle'
                        Cell.EntireRow.Copy
                        WS.Cells(2, C).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
                            xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
                        C = C + 1
                    End If
                Next Cell
            End With
        End If
    Next WS

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
````

Comment: Did you mean `Exit For` instead of the `Exit Sub`?

Comment: @GSerg, that made me giggle. Good reminder to *always step through thy code...* at the first, when you have issues.

Comment: That makes sense. I borrowed that snippet from someone else, which is why I referred to it as Frankencode. Does "stepping through the code" just mean carefully reading through it, or is there actually a program you can use?

Comment: Actually, I just tried the edit I suggested and all it did was loop through all the pages a transpose only one column in B2, instead of a column for every matching value

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the code. Set a breakpoint at the start, and then step through the code. See the *Debug* menu in the VB Editor.

Comment: @Ken White Thanks!